# The set of commutative matrices is an irreducible algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $A, B$ matrices $n \times n$.
Let $X = \left\{(A, B) \in \mathbb{A}^{2n^2} \mid AB = BA \right\}$.
Prove that $X$ is algebraic and irreducible variety.

Comment: [MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: @JKnecht : Could you approve the proposed edit?  (I've already done so; one more approval is needed.) $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

This is a theorem of Motzkin and Taussky, see:

T. Motzkin and O. Taussky-Todd, Pairs of matrices with property L. II,
Transactions of the AMS,
80
(1955)